# Why is pandas changing the column content when writing into a CSV?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm measuring response times from a REST API (Azure Function) to validate whether a trained model replies faster than the other. I created the following code to send 3 different texts (a short, a medium, and a long text) to the API endpoint. I do this for 3 different models I have trained.

```
for model in models:
    for text in texts:
        now = time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
        response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(text), headers=headers, timeout=360)
        print(now, response.elapsed.total_seconds(), model)#response.text)
        data = {now, response.elapsed.total_seconds(), model}
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([data])
        df.to_csv(r'D:\temp\times.csv', mode='a', index=False, header= False)
```

The print output looks perfectly fine like this:

```
16-07-2021 17:29:42 1.371914 trained_sm_95
16-07-2021 17:29:44 1.362347 trained_sm_95
16-07-2021 17:29:45 1.316506 trained_sm_95
16-07-2021 17:29:47 1.211846 trained_md_96
16-07-2021 17:29:48 1.214879 trained_md_96
16-07-2021 17:29:49 1.398838 trained_md_96
16-07-2021 17:29:50 1.236758 trained_lg_95
16-07-2021 17:29:52 1.204907 trained_lg_95
16-07-2021 17:29:53 1.416844 trained_lg_95
```

the output in the CSV however messes up the positions of the timestamp, response time, and the model name:

```
trained_sm_95,1.371914,16-07-2021 17:29:42
trained_sm_95,1.362347,16-07-2021 17:29:44
trained_sm_95,1.316506,16-07-2021 17:29:45
1.211846,trained_md_96,16-07-2021 17:29:47
1.214879,trained_md_96,16-07-2021 17:29:48
1.398838,trained_md_96,16-07-2021 17:29:49
1.236758,16-07-2021 17:29:50,trained_lg_95
1.204907,16-07-2021 17:29:52,trained_lg_95
16-07-2021 17:29:53,1.416844,trained_lg_95
```

I have no idea why the sequence of the columns is messed up. How can I get the same output for the CSV export as for the screenprint above?

PS: there might be a smarter way to utilize pandas in the loop - feel free to suggest improvements...

Comment: `print(data)` will show that the `set` doesn't keep the order of initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a `set`:

```
data = {now, response.elapsed.total_seconds(), model}  # <- set
```

Maybe you can use a list to maintain order:

```
data = [now, response.elapsed.total_seconds(), model]
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(data))
```

Comment: Since OP doesn't use the header there isn't any need to add it to the dataframe. The original `from_records` call is a reasonable way to setup the dataframe.